# Get color of contour

Tags: c++, objective-c, algorithm, opencv, geometry

I'm using `openCV` + `C++` to extract the contours of an image.

See these lines:

```
vector<vector<cv::Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2GRAY);

findContours( image, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0) );

for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) {
     // do stuff with contours[i];
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to extract the **extract the main-color** of the image.

> [From this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zMbq.png) --> extract color "blue" as RGB;

Any help how to implement this in C++ would be very appreciated.

---

**Note:** This question ([Finding contour color using opencv c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971432/finding-contour-color-using-opencv-c)) was all I've found during my research but it looks like 1.the question is Off-Topic & 2.the question didn't get answered.

Comment: THe main bulk of your question talks about getting average colours of the whole image yet the start of your question talks about contours. It's a little unclear about what you actually want to do.

Comment: please explain better what you want to achieve, maybe with some example images, marked contours and the desired result.

Comment: Still unclear... do you know in advance the color you want to extract? Just use `inRange` then

Comment: Nobody has yet understood the solution you expect... please tell us ;)